# Nodejs using variables on separated files

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to use and implementing `caminteJs` on nodejs, i created `models` folder and in that i have some database schema which wrapped into separated file as

```
user.js //contains user table schema
news.js //contains news table schema
```

into `index.js` which its into `models` folder i have:

```
var users = require( './user' );
var news = require( './news' );

module.exports = {
    users:users,
    news:news
};
```

`user.js` file content:

```
var schema = require('../config');
module.exports = function(schema){
    var users = schema.define('channels', {
         user_name: { type: schema.String, limit: 30 },
         ...
         created_at: { type: schema.Date },
         updated_at: { type: schema.Date }
    });

    return users;
};
```

`config.js` file content:

```
var caminte = require( 'caminte' ),
    Schema = caminte.Schema,
    config = {
        driver: "mysql",
        host: "localhost",
        port: "3306",
        username: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "test",
        pool: true
    },
    schema = new Schema( config.driver, config );

module.exports = {
    caminte: caminte,
    Schema: Schema,
    config: config,
    schema: schema
}
```

and then my `server.js` to use them:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' ),
    ...
    config = require( './config' ),
    models = require( './models' );

server.listen( port, function () {
    console.log( 'Server listening at port %d', port );
} );

io.on( 'connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on( "new_channel", function (data, device) {
        new models.channels( { channel_name: 'Peter' } );
        console.log( channel );
    } );
} );
```

I get this error on `user.js`:

```
TypeError: schema.define is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it should be:

```
var users = schema.schema.define('channels', {
```

Because you defined that here:

```
module.exports = {
    caminte: caminte,
    Schema: Schema,
    config: config,
    schema: schema // <- this
}
```

So `schema` in `user.js` is the same object you defined in the `module.exports`.

You could rewrite `user.js` as this:

```
var config = require('../config');
module.exports = function(schema){
    var users = config.schema.define('channels', {
         user_name: { type: config.schema.String, limit: 30 },
         ...
         created_at: { type: config.schema.Date },
         updated_at: { type: config.schema.Date }
    });

    return users;
};
```